# How do I exclude a folder from iTunes after it was automatically added?

Tags: itunes

I'm new to iTunes. I installed it and let it automatically scan my music. I didn't let it "consolidate" the media by using the iTunes directory because I have many tens of GBs and did not want to duplicate it (short on HD space in my laptop).

There are several music folders I want excluded from iTunes, but I could not find where it lists the folders included. I tried searching the web for this problem, but all I found were instructions on how to exclude folders during installation, which I already passed.

I have iTunes 9.0.3.15 installed.

How can I exclude a folder?

Answer (score 2):

[iTunes Folder Watch](http://albumbrowser.klarita.net/itfw.html) should be able to tackle this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

iTunes does not continuously scan folders on your computer and add any new tracks. This means you could just remove the tracks that you do not want in iTunes, and they will not be re-added.

Answer (score 1):

You have two easy ways to do this

1. If you can easily find the tracks you want to remove in iTunes, just select them in iTunes and hit delete.  This will remove them from itunes but not your hard drive (or at least prompt you with the option).
2. Delete every song in your library and then just manually re-add the ones you want to stay in there